# Is it possible to pass referer URL in the request header to React Native App using Deep Linking?

Tags: react-native, deep-linking, http-referer

My React Native app has a website version. When an user click a link to our website, it will open my App using Deep links. Now I want to send some data from that url to my app, specifically the referer field in request header (for tracking tool search, like google.com, etc. ). I already have this piece of code in my app :

```
 useEffect(() => {
        const subscription = Linking.addEventListener('url', navigateScreen);
        //navigateScreen is a function to navigate to screen of my App depending on url
        return () => {
            if (subscription) {
                subscription?.remove();
            }
        };
    }, [navigateScreen]);
```

So my question is can I have my App receive the request header of url or only the url itself ? If can how can I achieve it ?