# Can you get the referer url / source url from which a user deeplinked into app?

Tags: react-native

Say a user clicked a deeplink in their mobile browser and deeplink into the app.
We can get the deeplink itself with Linking.getInitialUrl() etc.
Is there any way to get access to the url a user was at in the browser when they clicked the deeplink?

So far I've googled around, read this [Is it possible to pass referer URL in the request header to React Native App using Deep Linking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73146561/is-it-possible-to-pass-referer-url-in-the-request-header-to-react-native-app-usi), and hoped that I have better luck.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.